# Blazor WebAssembly nginx server returns HTML on *.css or *.js files

Tags: html, nginx, blazor, mime-types, blazor-webassembly

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the resources such as `css` and `js` files are returned as same as the `index.html`:
[image]

Like in the picture, each of those `GET` calls return the content of `index.html` instead of the original content.
Meanwhile my nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {
    server_name <DOMAIN>;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    #add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "none";
    add_header X-Download-Options "noopen";
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1;mode=block";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer";
    client_max_body_size 1G;
    location /ん尺 {
        root /var/www/<DOMAIN>;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        index index.html;
        gzip_static on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_types *;
        gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
    }
 
  include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<DOMAIN>/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<DOMAIN>/privkey.pem;
}
```

As you can see the path is not `/` but `/ん尺` because the `/` path is running something else.
And at the same my `index.html` base is `<base href="/ん尺/">` so the resources point correctly in the beginning.

Is there something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Core hosted web app? This happens when the  document isn't found. You'll notice that the returned HTML isn't really the same as `index.html`, it contains an error message in the main section. What do your `link` and `style` tags look like? Are the CSS, JS files included in `wwwroot` or are you trying to load them from a different location?

Comment: Where are your files located? Is there a directory called `ん尺` in `/var/www/<DOMAIN>`? Otherwise, your `location` block will deliver `/var/www/<DOMAIN>/index.html` as defined in your `try_files` statement.

Comment: You can right-click on the URL that failed in the Network window and select `Open in New Tab` to see the actual result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nope, simple WebAssembly only template was used.

@RichardSmith files are located at `/var/www/<DOMAIN>/`, no further going down, `ん尺` is just a web location/path as root for this webapp. In fact the `/` document and the favicon are delivered correctly without any issue, the folders that follow like `css` or `_framework` should be reached, but it does seem not the case.

@PanagiotisKanavos the actual result is the `index.html` result, not the actual css of js.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry, I'm gonna answer what's left, links look simple like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">`. No, the js is between `js` and `_framework` folders and the css is in the `css` folder, so a different location, just one step down from root.

Comment: Could you add the list of files in /var/www (output of `find -type f /var/www`) and the exact URL you're using to load the page in your browser?